# How to add a custom product template in NopCommerce plugin

Tags: nopcommerce

I have created a plugin but it needs a customised product template and I cant get that to work. Could someone please help me understand what I have done wrong?

So far I have:

1. gone to https://example.com/Admin/Template/List and added a new product template
   1a. set the view path to "myCustomPlugin.Views.Product.ProductTemplateCustom.Simple"
2. gone to https://example.com/Admin/Product/Edit/46 and set that product with the new product template
3. in my plugin code I have created the template in: myCustomPlugin\Views\Product\ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml
4. loaded the product page

when I load the product page I get:

> InvalidOperationException: InvalidOperationException: The view 'ProductTemplateCustom.Simple' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Product/ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml /Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Shared/ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml /Views/Product/ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml /Views/Shared/ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml /Pages/Shared/ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml

- I have checked `Nop.Web\Plugins\myCustomPlugin\Views\Product` and `ProductTemplateCustom.Simple.cshtml` has been copied over.
- I have looked `RouteProvider.cs` expecting some routing configuration needing to be added to my plugin but I can't see anything
- [Their documentation](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/running-your-store/system-administration/templates.html#add-a-new-template) says I have to add a new product template to `Views\Product` so I have done that but it exists in my plugin path and I can't work out how to get NopCommerce to look in that location

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for is [IViewLocationExpander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander?view=aspnetcore-5.0). In simple words, this interface allows you to add custom view locations, so you can override the default view from your plugin.

You can find an implementation in *Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Themes\ThemeableViewLocationExpander.cs*

The straightforward way is to provide the full path of the view. However, I prefer using the ViewLocationExpander, it feels more orderly and neat.